# Put 3 balls randomly into 4 cups. Find the probability that the maximum number of balls in the cup is 2

Tags: probability

Put 3 balls randomly into 4 cups. Find the probability that the maximum number of balls in the cup is 2. I know the answer is $\frac{9}{16}$, but I can't calculate it forward. With backward way, I can calculate. As the maximum number of balls in the cup must be 1, 2, and 3. Let $A_n$ represent that the maximum number of balls is $n$.

$P(A_1)=A_4^3/4^3=\frac{3}{8}$

$P(A_3)=A_4^1/4^3=\frac{1}{16}$

As $P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)=1$, so $P(A_2)=1-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{9}{16}$.

But, how to calculate the $P(A_2)$ forward? I think it is

$P(A_2)=A_4^2/4^3=\frac{3}{16}$

which is not right. Where was I wrong?

Comment: Two cases: second ball same cup as first ball, or second ball in different cup.

Comment: So, how to calculate it forward? @DanielMathias

Comment: @DanielMathias From your hint, I think it is $(A_4^2\times 2)/4^3=3/8$, which is wrong either.

Comment: Second ball in same cup is $1/4$ and in different cup is $3/4$

Comment: Choose a cup to hold two balls ($4$ ways) and a second to hold one ($3$ ways), and select which of the three balls is the singleton ($3$ choices); divide by the total number of possible assignments of balls to cups ($4^3=64$), to get $(4 \times 3 \times 3) / 4^3 = 9/16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first ball can go in any cup.

Case 1:
The second ball goes into the same cup as the first ball. Probability: $\frac{1}{4}$
In this case, the third ball must go into any other cup. Probability: $\frac{3}{4}$
Probability of success with this case: $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$

Case 2:
The second ball goes into any other cup. Probability: $\frac{3}{4}$
In this case, the third ball must go into one of the non-empty cups. Probability: $\frac{1}{2}$
Probability of success with this case: $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{8}$

Total probability of success: $\frac{3}{16}+\frac{3}{8}=\frac{9}{16}$